# Find nearest row match using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have sample table as below

```
Type    Format  W   D   L   Gauge
Roxy    Rubbers 31  1   1   3
Roxy    Rubbers 36  0   48  4
Roxy    Rubbers 36  1   1   3
```

Here is my sub

```
Sub Calculate()
   Dim Format, Gauge, Width, Depth, Length As String 
   Format = Sheets("inputs").Range("H26")
   Gauge = Sheets("inputs").Range("I26")
   Width = Sheets("inputs").Range("J26")
   Depth = Sheets("inputs").Range("K26")
   Length = Sheets("inputs").Range("L26")

   Dim vArray() As Variant
   vArray = Range("myRange")

   Dim i As Long
   For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
       Debug.Print vArray(i, 1)
   Next
End Sub
```

How do I find nearest row using VBA?
Gauge and format needs to be exact match and for W/D/L need to return nearest match

Example:
For Rubbers, 3 gauge, 30x12x12 input it should return first row as result

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "nearest" you meant nearest volume (in the case of no exaxt matching), I suggest this function that returns the right range given those parameters. Note that I assumed that your "Gauge" column is next to the "Format" one (columns H and I as in your code) while your pictures shows that gauge comes last...

```
Option Explicit

Function findNearestRow(FindIn As Range, Format As String, _
    Gauge As String, Width As Double, Depth As Double, Length As Double) As Range

    Dim F As String, G As String, W As Double, D As Double, L As Double
    Dim i As Long, best As Long, vol As Double, diff As Double, minDiff As Double
    minDiff = 99999999

    vol = Width * Depth * Length
    For i = 1 To FindIn.Rows.Count
        F = FindIn.Cells(i, 1).Value
        G = FindIn.Cells(i, 2).Value
        If F = Format And G = Gauge Then
            W = FindIn.Cells(i, 3).Value
            D = FindIn.Cells(i, 4).Value
            L = FindIn.Cells(i, 5).Value
            If W = Width And D = Depth And L = Length Then
                Set findNearestRow = FindIn.Rows(i)
                Exit Function
            End If

            diff = Abs(W * D * L - vol)
            If diff < minDiff Then
               minDiff = diff
               best = i
            End If
        End If
   Next
   If minDiff < 1000 Then Set findNearestRow = FindIn.Rows(best)
   ' Else it returns null, nearest matching too far

End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = findNearestRow(FindIn:=Range("H2:L20"), _
                Format:=Sheets("inputs").Range("H26"), _
                Gauge:=Sheets("inputs").Range("I26"), _
                Width:=Sheets("inputs").Range("J26"), _
                Depth:=Sheets("inputs").Range("K26"), _
                Length:=Sheets("inputs").Range("L26"))

    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "no matching found"
    Else
        r.Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first `AutoFilter()` the exact matches and then loop through filtered cells for the *nearest* triple:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Calculate()
    Dim Format As String
    Dim Gauge As Long, Width As Long, Depth As Long, Length As Long
    Dim nearestRate As Double
    Dim nearestRng As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheets("inputs")
        Format = .Range("H26").Value2
        Gauge = .Range("I26").Value2
        Width = .Range("J26").Value2
        Depth = .Range("K26").Value2
        Length = .Range("L26").Value2
        With .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Format
            .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=Gauge
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
                nearestRate = 100000000#
                For Each cell In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    UpdateNearest cell, Width, Depth, Length, nearestRate, nearestRng
                Next
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function UpdateNearest(rng As Range, refVal1 As Long, refVal2 As Long, refVal3 As Long, nearestRate As Double, nearestRng As Range) As Long
    Dim rate As Double

    rate = Sqr((rng.Value - refVal1) ^ 2 + (rng.Offset(, 1).Value - refVal1) ^ 2 + (rng.Offset(, 2).Value - refVal2) ^ 2)
    If rate < nearestRate Then
        nearestRate = rate
        Set nearestRng = rng
    End If
End Function
```

the `UpdateNearest()` function assumes a criteria of minimum differences squares sum. but you can adapt to your actual (and unknown) needs